# C# ManagementScope loses connection and causes memory leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, wmi

I'm using WMI for monitoring all our servers through a small C# service, which creates a bunch of ManagementScopes (one per server it should monitor) and periodically polls for CPU load etc.

However every once in a while it starts throwing COMExceptions, with the message "The RPC server is unavailable". Now that's fair enough if it was true, however I can manully connect to the server just fine, **and** if I create a new ManagementScope to the same server, I can reconnect without problems!

There's a problem with this approach though: It leaks memory :-(

ManagementScope has no Close, Dispose or similar cleanup function, and leaks memory when just garbage collected. This is, according to all my google searches, a problem with the underlying WMI components, and as such not a .Net issue.

So I figure my best approach is to solve the COMException issue, and just staying with the original ManagementScope - however if I manually call Connect on the scope after the COMException, it **does** return true (as in "Yes I've got a connection), but at first attempt at getting data from it, it throws another COMException.

I've tried quite a few things, but I simply cannot figure out why this happens :-(

The code is quite large, therefore I haven't pasted it here (and it's split into a lot of classes)

But basically I create a scope, and then call the following methods:

```
public ManagementObject GetSingleObject(string query)
{
    using (var searcher = CreateSearcher(query))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var collection = searcher.Get())
            {
                return collection
                        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private ManagementObjectSearcher CreateSearcher(string query)
{
    return new ManagementObjectSearcher(_scope, new ObjectQuery(query), _options);
}
```

If you need more code, let me know :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason the exception isn't thrown until you try to get data is because the connection isn't opened until then. ManagementObjectSearcher class MSDN says "When the Get() method on this object is invoked, the ManagementObjectSearcher executes the given query in the specified scope"

Comment: That seems logical yes. What I fail to understand is why the connection doesn't work. If I create a brand new ManagementScope with the same options, etc. It'll work fine (for a while).